# Save many numpy variables in one file

Tags: python, numpy

I have a script that gathers data using `np.loadtxt()` from different folders.
I would like to be able to save all of them in the current folder without having to do a `savetxt()` for each.

The purpose is to have a portable file to execute the script on a different computer.

Comment: What have you tried and what hasn't worked?

Comment: I don't quite know enough about what you are doing with the data or what the data looks like. My first inclination is to store using `pickle`, that way you can retrieve the numpy file directly, but I don't know if you have a different intended use for the data. For example, does it have to be in a text file?

Comment: Pickle as I understand also needs to explicitly save each of the variables. I wonder if there is a way to save all the numpy variables loaded by the script as to loaded afterward.

Comment: What's the mix of `shape` and `dtype`?

Comment: dtype are all the same (numpy.ndarray). Shapes differ in both: columns and rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the NumPy [`save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) function like so:

```
import numpy as np
# Create sample data
a = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
b = np.array([4.0, 5.0])
# Save to file
np.save('myfile.npy', [a, b])
# Load back in
a2, b2 = np.load('myfile.npy')
```

Note that though the documentation does not state this explicitly, you can indeed store multiple arrays of different sizes in a single file, as above (really this is done by storing each array as an element of a 1D array of dtype `object`, but never mind the implementation).

Comment: Why not `np.savez`?

Comment: @hpaulj That's fine as well. I usually use `np.save`, maybe because it reads nicer.

Comment: While I need to add manually each variable name to the 1D array, it is much easier and less messy than write `np.savetxt` for each one.

Comment: For multiple arrays use `np.savez` otherwise you will get ``ValueError: could not broadcast...`.